# change mutt indicator color when hovering a new message

Tags: mutt, dotfiles, solarized

I want to change the color of the text when hovering a new message in mutts index.

Right now I have

```
color indicator  color111 color236 #indicator line
```

and

```
color index      color082 color237 ~N # new message color
```

How can I set a color for the new message when being hovered by the indicator line?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Every message can have only one color pair (text color, background).

*indicator* has precedence before *index* normal color. Probably even before any other color (deleted, tagged, …).

You can set `arrow_cursor` to see the color of a new message and also see where the indicator is. It changes indicator from whole line to arrow `->` at the beggining of the line. Indicator color applies only to the arrow, the rest of the line is colored according to your other color rules.

```
set arrow_cursor
```

To toggle the settings use macro, or just `:toggle arrow_cursor`

```
macro index,browser,alias,generic ,<space> \
"<enter-command>toggle arrow_cursor<enter>" \
"Toggle cursor arrow/line"
```